# NoSuchMethod Exception when calling a method

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this if condition where I am calling a method inside, when reaching that part of the code I get the NoSuchMethodError exception. The called method inside of the if condition works perfectly fine as I do get the OTP code.

```
      if (isUserExists) {
        await AmplifyInstance().signInUser(_phoneNumber).then((status) {
          if (status['result']) {
            //some code here
          }
        });
      }
```

Called Method -

```
  Future<dynamic> signInUser(userPhoneNumber) async {
    print('SignIn User');
    try {
      await Amplify.Auth.signIn(
        username: userPhoneNumber,
        password: userPhoneNumber + 'Bol',
      );
      statusMessage['result'] = true;
    } on AuthException catch (e) {
      statusMessage['result'] = false;
      statusMessage['errorMessage'] = e.message;
    }
  }
```

Here the statusMessage returns true to the calling method.

Here is the snip of the error I get -
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`signInUser` doesn't return a value. Also since you're using `await` on line 166, you don't need `then` and you could access `statusMessage` variable on the next line.

If `statusMessage` is not accessible in that scope, you could return `statusMessage` from `signInUser`.